# BInary Search Tree iterator c# without parent property

Tags: c#, iterator, binary-search-tree

I recently started making a Binary Search Tree in C# in order to practice. After completing this task I decided to implement `ICollection<T>` so that my tree can be used with a `foreach`and just in general in order for me to practice.

I've constructed my classes in such a way that I have a `Node<T>` class and a `BinarySearchTree<T>` class that contains a `Node<T>` a `Count` integer and a `IsReadOnly` boolean. This is my Node Class:

```
    internal class Node<T>: INode<T> where T: IComparable<T>
  {
    public Node<T> RightChildNode { get; set; }
    public Node<T> LeftChildNode { get; set; }
    public T Key { get; set; }

    //some methods go here
  }
```

and this is my BST class:

```
    public class BinarySearchTree<T>: ICollection<T> where T: IComparable<T>
{
    internal Node<T> Root { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; private set; }
    public bool IsReadOnly => false;

    //some methods go here
}
```

Now in order to implement `ICollection<T>` i obviously need an enumerator which I have (partly) implemented as such:

```
    internal class BinarySearchTreeEnumerator<T> : IEnumerator<T> where T: IComparable<T>
{
    private BinarySearchTree<T> _parentTree;
    private BinarySearchTree<T> _currentTree;
    private Node<T> _currentNode => _currentTree.Root;
    private T _currentKey;

    public T Current => _currentNode.Key;

    /// <summary>
    /// generic constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tree"></param>
    public BinarySearchTreeEnumerator(BinarySearchTree<T> tree)
    {
        this._parentTree = tree;
    }

    object IEnumerator.Current => Current;

    void IDisposable.Dispose(){}

    //pls
    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        if (_currentTree is null)
        {
            _currentTree = _parentTree;
        }
        var leftSubtree = this._currentTree.GetLeftSubtree();
        var rightSubtree = this._currentTree.GetRightSubtree();

        if (!(leftSubtree is null))
        {
            this._currentTree = leftSubtree;

        }
        else if (!(rightSubtree is null))
        {
            this._currentTree = rightSubtree;

        }
        else
        {

        }

    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        _currentTree = _parentTree;
    }
}
```

now my issue is quite obviously with the `MoveNext()` method. It doesn't work now because what it does is it just goes down the tree on the leftmost possible path and then gets stuck when it gets to the end of that path. I know I can fix this problem by adding a `Parent` property to my `Node<T>` class and then whenever I reach the end of a path in my tree I can just go one Node up and check if there's a different path... However this would mean completely changing my original class and I would prefer not to do that.

Is this just unavoidable? Is there any way to solve this issue *without* changing my `Node<T>` class in such a way?

## Edit: I Made a thing but its not working :/

```
      public bool MoveNext()
    {
        if (_currentNode is null)
        {
            this._currentNode = _parentTree.Root;
            this._nodeStack.Push(_currentNode);
            return true;
        }
        var leftNode = this._currentNode.LeftChildNode;
        var rightNode = this._currentNode.RightChildNode;

        if (!(leftNode is null))
        {
            this._currentNode = leftNode;
            this._nodeStack.Push(_currentNode);
            return true;
        }
        else if (!(rightNode is null))
        {
            this._currentNode = rightNode;
            this._nodeStack.Push(_currentNode);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            //current node does not have children
            var parent = this._nodeStack.Pop();
            do
            {

                if (parent is null)
                {
                    return false;
                }

            } while (!(parent.RightChildNode is null));

            this._currentNode = parent.RightChildNode;
            this._nodeStack.Push(_currentNode);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier to use recursion to implement this; for example:

**Recursive version (for balanced trees only)**

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    return enumerate(Root).GetEnumerator();
}

IEnumerable<T> enumerate(Node<T> root)
{
    if (root == null)
        yield break;

    yield return root.Key;

    foreach (var value in enumerate(root.LeftChildNode))
        yield return value;

    foreach (var value in enumerate(root.RightChildNode))
        yield return value;
}
```

These are members of `BinarySearchTree<T>`.

Given the above implementation, then the following code:

```
BinarySearchTree<double> tree = new BinarySearchTree<double>();

tree.Root = new Node<double> {Key = 1.1};

tree.Root.LeftChildNode  = new Node<double> {Key = 2.1};
tree.Root.RightChildNode = new Node<double> {Key = 2.2};

tree.Root.LeftChildNode.LeftChildNode   = new Node<double> { Key = 3.1 };
tree.Root.LeftChildNode.RightChildNode  = new Node<double> { Key = 3.2 };
tree.Root.RightChildNode.LeftChildNode  = new Node<double> { Key = 3.3 };
tree.Root.RightChildNode.RightChildNode = new Node<double> { Key = 3.4 };

foreach (var value in tree)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

produces this output:

```
1.1
2.1
3.1
3.2
2.2
3.3
3.4
```

WARNING: Stack space is limited to 1MB for a 32-bit process and 4MB for a 64-bit process, so using recursion is likely to run out of stack space if the tree is degenerate (badly unbalanced).

**Non-recursive version**

You can implement the non-recursive version fairly simply, like so:

```
IEnumerable<T> enumerate(Node<T> root)
{
    var stack = new Stack<Node<T>>();
    stack.Push(root);

    while (stack.Count > 0)
    {
        var node = stack.Pop();

        if (node == null)
            continue;

        yield return node.Key;
        stack.Push(node.RightChildNode);
        stack.Push(node.LeftChildNode);
    }
}
```

This returns the elements in the same order as the recursive version.

Since this version will not run out of stack space even for a degenerate tree, it is preferable to the recursive version.

Comment: Suggesting recursion on an eumerator of a collection is a little... risky let's say. Perhaps in a self balancing tree there are little risks (because the maximum height is low), but in a not-self balancing tree the depth could grow quite quickly if you add the elements like 4000, 3999, 3998... 0

Comment: ok this looks quite interesting. I don't exactly understand how it works but I think this is because I don't fully understand `yield` right now. I will have to study it. If it works it works though, thanks :).

Comment: @Sreini `yield` is the magic keyword that makes `GetEnumerator()` easy to implement. It is very very rare that someone implements a `IEnumerator` nowadays.

Comment: @xanatos Yes it would run out of stack space after 256K entries for a degenerate tree which had only, say, left branches (or 128K entries for a 64-bit program). I'll add that  as a warning.

Answer (score 0):

If you add to your enumerator a

```
private List<Node<T>> _currentParentNodes = new List<Node<T>>();
```

and use it like a stack, each time you go down a level you push the current node to `currentParentNodes`, each time you have to go up you pop the parent node from `currentParentNodes`, then all your problems will pop away :-)

Comment: oh duh of course! I'll have to rename `_parentTree` though I think because the naming would be confusing. But thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a depth-first-search(DFS) approach? It has a recursive nature which is hard to save as a state (it uses the call stack).

Maybe consider the broad-first-search (BFS) approach, which is iterative. You'd only need a currentNode and a Queue.

The rule would be

```
current = Queue.poll();
For child in current
     Queue.offer(child);
```

At init you would do

```
Queue.offer(rootNode);
```

I apologize for my poor formatting and syntax, mobile user here.
Andres